# Marvel movies which are not part of MCU

Tags: marvel

I am a big fan of the MCU but I know there is much more to Marvel than that.
I am trying to find a list of Marvel movies but I am always directed to the list of MCU movies only.

I know X-Men and Deadpool are also Marvel movies that are not part of the MCU, but are the others?

Is there a list of movies based on Marvel characters by date of release?

Comment: X-Men ___was___ a Fox franchise but Disney and so Marvel took over parts of Fox and so it became a Marvel franchise through time because of the acquisition. Could you clarify whether you want to know what films Marvel have created when Marvel was in control of them or if any film Marvel owns even if they acquired it later counts? Also what sorts of films are we talking here? And to be honest this has potential for being too broad.

Comment: For your answer though see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Entertainment#Film).

Comment: Yes, I want to know the films even if Marvel took control later on. for example if they took over X-Men I would also want to see the previous X-Men movies.

Comment: And as a new user, if you don't mind giving a piece of advice and let me know what is wrong with my question so I get downvotes, so I can learn for the next questions. thanks. @TheLethalCarrot

Comment: TBH it's a bit unclear about what you're after and the fact that it can be googled extremely easily usually leads to downvotes.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear as I don't understand what's the distinction between movies may have "taken over". I also strongly suggest editing in why the link provided in comments don't seem to answer your question.

Comment: I assume that Mor Zamir is asking about any and all movies (and possibly TV shows) based on any and all characters in Marvel Comics comic books, whether or not those movies are part of the MCU and regardless of which studios made those movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Wikipedia pages that will probably help.

1) The list of films based on Marvel Comics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_Marvel_Comics

and

2) The list of television series based on Marvel Comics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_series_based_on_Marvel_Comics

Having seen most of the movies/shows on these lists, they seem pretty complete to me - though there may still be some obscure entries missing.